# Library of Congress RDF files-issue with accessing connected items through Sparql in JAVA

Tags: sparql, rdf, triples

I am facing issues to fetch Library of Congress RDF Triples files connected items through SPARQL in Java. Can any one help me please.

When I fetched the data using SPARQL Fuseki server its working fine. But in Java its not showing the data related using nodes like below.

Data:

`_:bnode11385494358076243167 <http://www.loc.gov/mads/rdf/v1#variantLabel> "Theft"@en .`

Query:

```
String queryString=     
        "SELECT  ?variantLabel"+
        "WHERE {"+ 
        "_:bnode11385494358076243167  <http://www.loc.gov/mads/rdf/v1#variantLabel> ?variantLabel.}";
```

Comment: No space before `WHERE` and also possibly https://stackoverflow.com/tags/blank-nodes/info

Comment: Thanks Stanislav Kralin. This is happening because of space issues.I deleted all the spaces. it's working fine now.

Comment: This is not Q&A style. IMO the correction of the SPARQL is not an edited but the answer of this question.